# One way binding with ngModel in angular 4 it is not working with Observables

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable, ngrx

[image][image: ][1]]
I have an array which I have declared with Observables, in the array it is showing with console.log but in the dropdown I can see that only when click to drop down below than it is the id or name but I wan't if one that object has an string into that should shown me in the dropdown which string below to the project for example 32323 it is responsible for this project and when I open this project should show me on dropdown that responsible.
This is my code.

```
 cluster$: Observable<DropdownOption[]>;

 selectClusterOptions = createSelector(
    selectClusters,
    clusters => {
      const options: DropdownOption[] = [];
      options.push(...clusters.map(cluster => ({ key: cluster.id, value: cluster.name })).toArray());
      return options;
    }
  );


   this.cluster$ = store.pipe(select(this.selectClusterOptions));
```

This is the HTML

```
<app-dropdown label="Cluster" labelWidth="75px" optionWidth="170px" [items]="cluster$ | async" [ngModel]="(selectValueItem$ | async).clusterId"></app-dropdown>
```

Comment: use as `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: [(ngModel)] or two way data binding doesn't work with async

Comment: you can try using `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` whenever data is updated

Answer (score 0):

In order to do 2 way binding you have to have to use `[(ngModel)]`

```
<app-dropdown label="Cluster" labelWidth="75px" optionWidth="170px" [items]="cluster$ | async" [(ngModel)]="(selectValueItem$ | async).clusterId"></app-dropdown>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is showing me this error.
 Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 21 in [(selectValueItem$ | async).clusterId=$event]

Comment: You cant two way bind into an observable. I didn't see that

Comment: Yepp and I have google for it, but the problem it is maybe I think in this items cluster$ | async